# Container gets stopped after starting

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

I have my Docker file , build through it in the Docker engine , and then run the Docker image using `docker run -td --name <imagename>`
Checks for it, it keeps running in the Docker engine.

But when I tag it to Bluemix and then push it to Bluemix containers(gets available in catalog), and then I ran

```
cf ic run -td --name ifx2container registry.ng.bluemix.net/namespace_container/ifx2:informixinstall
```

This creates the container but it gets stopped automatically after few seconds of start

Comment: Did you check logs for any hints? Try `cf ic logs <container id>` to view the logs for any error messages. You can post the output in your question as well so someone can help. Another option is for you to add your Dockerfile in the question for someone to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

do run docker with

```
docker run -itd
```

not with

```
docker run -td

-i              : Keep STDIN open even if not attached
```

source : https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your container has a long-running command. Per docs: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_planning_container_ov.html#container_planning_images

> To keep a container up and running at least one long-running process is required to be included in the container image. For example, echo "Hello world" is a short running process. If no other command is specified in the image, the container shuts down after the command is executed. To transform the echo "Hello world" command into a long running process, you can, for example, loop it multiple times, or include the echo command into another long running process inside your app.

Also, by default containers in Bluemix run in detached mode. You can review supported run flags here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__run